# UTF-16 OR utf8mb

Tags: mysql, database

I'm planning to build a multilingual website and I've doubts whether I should use UTF-16 OR UTF8MB4.

I would love if you can help me decide and also provide me short explanation what are the differences between those two.

Thanks

Comment: utf8mb4 should *always* be your default pick unless you have a very specific requirement not to. UTF-16 is largely a dead encoding (but there's some very specific exceptions).

Comment: This is a pretty broad question, easily answered by reading related documentation. You are not asking about a specific coding problem, and that's the guideline for appropriate questions on Stack Overflow. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. So with respect, I am voting to close this question.